# Using Refresh Token on Gmail API. Keeping track of old keys

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

### TL;DR

The problem here is that I cannot do a `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` without first doing `setAccessToken()` and in order to do `setAccessToken()` I need to know the previous access token.

If I try to `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` without first calling `setAccessToken()` I get "LogicException: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken"

If I try to `setAccessToken()` with only the `refresh_token` value, it fails as well with `Invalid token format`

**The only way it works is by supplying a FULL valid auth token bundle, not just the refresh token.**

### I am using this script to get the first auth and generate the refresh token:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName('Gmail API Generate Refresh Token');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_MODIFY);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

// Request authorization from the user.
$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
print 'Enter verification code: ';
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for an access token.
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
}
print "\n\nBelow is the refresh token.\n\n";
print "Use this token with an authenticated Google_Client object to refresh auth tokens.\n";
print "This string MUST be saved otherwise you will need user approval again\n\n";
print $client->getRefreshToken();

file_put_contents('token.json', json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
print "\n\nThe first auth token bundle has been saved to token.json\n";
```

### Overview

- I have a **fully-working** server-side application that is used to interact with a single user's Gmail inbox.

  - I have the API creds, and the refresh token saved in persistent secure storage.
  - The application can succesfully interact with Gmail until the access token expires.

> Overall the goal here is to be able to interact with the Gmail API when the application has ONLY the following: valid client id/secret, and a refresh_token. What I'm finding is that I need to keep track of the auth tokens as well as the refresh token.

### Here is the issue I'm facing:

- Once the access token expires, I cannot generate a new one using only my API creds and the refresh token.
- I get an error `invalid_grant` if I try to call `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` with only the refresh token string as a parameter.
- The only way I can get it to give me a new token is to supply the refresh token AND the current access token information!

  - Not only do I need the original access token itself, but I also need the `created` and `expires_in` values.

> I have to pass it a full array of info: `[access_token, expires_in, created, refresh_token]` otherwise it simply won't work!

**Clearly I'm doing something wrong here, I would think all I need is the refresh token to generate access tokens as needed.**

---

### **[PHP] Here are some snippets:**

*(note these are dev only, I'm not planning to hard-code secrets in the code)*

**Here is what I would "expect" to work (this does NOT work):** 
Error here is `invalid_grant`

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_MODIFY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // This is the REFRESH token
    $token = '1\/\/0dKcfaketokentokentokenfaketoken-L9IriuoNveLzVQ1w4-lPfakeEPn1R1NjcOK2ISE--O1PO1yEtokenr87E';

    // var_dump just for sanity to ensure this returns true
    var_dump($client->isAccessTokenExpired());

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      var_dump($client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($token));
    }
```

THIS WORKS, Because I'm feeding it the full `$token` array (or is it because I've pre-provided setAccessToken() beforehand. :

```
    $token = array();
    $token['access_token'] = '<<SCRUBBED_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN>>>';
    $token['expires_in'] = 3599;
    $token['refresh_token'] = '<<SCRUBBED_REFRESH_TOKEN>>';
    $token['created'] = 1587447211;

    // If I leave out ANY of the values above, the token refresh does not work! 

    // omitted some Gmail client configuration and setup. 

    $this->client->setAccessToken($token);

    if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      $this->accessToken =  $this->client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($token);
    }
    else {
      $this->accessToken = $this->client->getAccessToken();
    }
    $this->service = new Google_Service_Gmail($this->client);
```

***Clue:***

> I noticed on https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/1fdfe942f9aaf3064e621834a5e3047fccb3a6da/src/Google/Client.php#L275
>   The `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` will fall back to the existing token, this explains why it'll work when I pre-set an existing token. At least that mystery seems to be solved. Does not explain why it's still not working without a pre-set token.

I would expect it to just work like this:

```
    // Omitted initial Gmail client setup

    if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      $this->accessToken =  $this->client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken('<MY_REFRESH_TOKEN');
    }
    else {
      $this->accessToken = $this->client->getAccessToken();
    }
    $this->service = new Google_Service_Gmail($this->client);
```

This also doesn't work (confirmed that the `getRefreshToken()` value is good):

```
$this->client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($this->client->getRefreshToken());
```

Comment: Is the issue solved with the answer below? If not can you provide info on where are you at now?

Comment: please edit your question and add the authorization code you are using so we can see where you are getting your refresh token from.

Comment: @Kassy no it's not solved. I'm still working on this problem. The main problem is I cannot call `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken` without first applying the token set with `setAccessToken` which leads to either issue: `LogicException: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken` or `invalid_grant`

Comment: @DaImTo I've edited the question with a full client instantiation snippet and re-worded some stuff to make it clearer. I've tried your suggestions and it's not working. I can use the refresh token ONLY if I've already provided the full token set.

Comment: @emmdee please edit your question and show us where you are getting the refresh token from.  That one is not valid  Where are you getting this token from?

Comment: @DaImTo the refresh token is a string from the token.json acquired during initial Oauth setup (not within this app).  I can assure you it is for sure valid because when I supply it with the full token json (or array) it refreshes without issue. The problem here is that I cannot do a `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()` without first doing `setAccessToken()` and in order to do `setAccessToken()` I need to know the previous access token.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.  Please supply a full [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The question is missing critical information as to where the hard coded token is comming from and being stored.

Comment: the expected behavior is in the original post, under the **bolded** heading `Here is what I would "expect" to work`. The question has been edited with the original refresh token generation script as requested.

Comment: Have you tried generating new credentials for the application? Also, are there any changes in your your code? How do you have the application set up?

Comment: @Kessy Hi, yes I've generated countless tokens while troubleshooting. See the comments on the below answer for further discussion on what I've tried. This is a background scheduled job that runs several times per day. There is no user session. The token needs to be generated every time the app starts up (several times per day) without any user interaction. It works fine as long as I keep track of the old/expired access token alongside everything else. ONLY when I supply the old token does it work. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 4):

> invalid_grant

Means that the token you are using is invaid or expired, or you are trying to use a valid refresh token with a client id and secret that were not used to create it. In this case you are sending an object and should only be sending valid refresh token there for the value you are sending to the method is incorect.

This `fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken` method takes a refresh token not an object.  Just pass it the refresh token.

Example: [ClientTest.php#L485](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/2a652bfaab250ea7b6dfae46a917f2a6d7997f6f/tests/Google/ClientTest.php#L485)

## client creation

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
$client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());
```

## check for expiration and refresh if needed.

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());      
    }
```

## Note

If you are are getting the refresh token saved and created by another script that the system refreshing the token must use the same client id and client secret IE (client_secrets.json) in order to be able to use it to refresh the access.   It cant just be another one in the same project it must be the same secrets.

[also see Oauth2Authencation.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/Oauth2Authentication.php)

### Full example saving token to folder

[oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

[Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Gets the Google client refreshing auth if needed.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Initializes a client object.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getGoogleClient() {
    $client = getOauth2Client();

    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the Google client object.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Scopes will need to be changed depending upon the API's being accessed.
 * Example:  array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY, Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS)
 * List of Google Scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function buildClient(){
    
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}

/**
 * Builds the redirect uri.
 * Documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/auth/installed-app#choosingredirecturi
 * Hostname and current server path are needed to redirect to oauth2callback.php
 * @return A redirect uri.
 */
function getRedirectUri(){

    //Building Redirect URI
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                    //returns the current URL
    if(strrpos($url, '?') > 0)
        $url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '?') );  // Removing any parameters.
    $folder = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') );   // Removeing current file.
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $folder. '/oauth2callback.php';
}


/**
 * Authenticating to Google using Oauth2
 * Documentation:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2
 * Returns a Google client with refresh token and access tokens set. 
 *  If not authencated then we will redirect to request authencation.
 * @return A google client object.
 */
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Note: refresh token is only guaranteed to return with the first call the first time the user consents to your accessing their data there google assumes you have stored the refresh token so they dont send a new one. This is why only the access token is saved again after the system automatically refresh the access token using the stored refresh token.

Comment: Hi thanks, unfortunately this returns: ```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

Comment: Confirmed that `$client->getRefreshToken();` is returning the appropriate refresh token. Still getting `invalid_grant` error :(

Comment: Ok actually I got past that by removing the `setAccessToken()` beforehand. Now the error is `LogicException: refresh token must be passed in or set as part of setAccessToken` which I'll look into. Thanks again.

Comment: Again you need to send a valid refresh token figure out where your getting your refresh token from make sure that its set.

Comment: I think this is why it's behaving like this https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/1fdfe942f9aaf3064e621834a5e3047fccb3a6da/src/Google/Client.php#L275
it's falling back on the existing token.

Comment: The refresh token string is fine. Confirmed that `$client->getRefreshToken();` is returning the appropriate refresh token. The refresh token is saved in my database as a string. It's for sure valid I can refresh the auth successfully if I had first supplied the full token bundle (the question has been edited to better explain this)

Comment: **Please edit your question and include this code.**   If its in your database have you tested fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken before saving to the database and then after retrieving from the database.   Google does not lie if they say your token is invalid its invalid.   Where are you getting it from Exactly show the code or we cant help you.

Comment: @DalmTo the full refresh token generation script I'm using has been posted in the original question.

Comment: @DalmTo it's starting to sound like the correct answer is: "You must keep track of both the refresh token AND the auth token bundle, you cannot refresh an auth token with just a refresh token" --is that correct?

Comment: Well I have been a contributor and used this client library since 2012. I know how it works and I know the messages it comes with.    The library is stable and in maintenance mode. This is not an error on the libraries side. You only need the refresh token and the client id and secret that it was used to create in order to refresh the access token. 
https://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: Very helpful.  I've been working with your examples/links to see what im missing, however I see in your example you are setting `setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token'])` before generating a new one with the client & refresh token - that's what I'm trying to get around. In my case there is no user session info, this is a scheduled back end job that runs on various systems, it's not a user browser session with an active token all the time, this script runs a few times per day but always has the refresh tok and the authenticated client (same client creds that generated the refresh token)